# Usage of subjunctive mood

Tags: subjunctives, present-subjunctive

> 1) I wish he were kinder to me.
>
> 2) I wish he would be kinder to me.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: They basically mean the same thing, both would be said at a present time.